# s3-put fails to send file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to send a file to amazon s3 using the s3-bash scripts.

Using this command:

```
./s3-put -T ./test2 -k <mykey> -s ./<mysecretkeyfile> /mybucketname
```

leads to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MalformedXML</Code><Message>The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema</Message><RequestId>xxx</RequestId><HostId>xxx</HostId></Error>
```

Any idea? I just want to send a file via bash.

Comment: I just came across the same error using another tool, s3cmd. Turned out you need to add trailing slash to the bucket name: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd#c000229. (Maybe it's the same for s3-bash and you won't need to add the *filename*. Or maybe not.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it: the bucket name needs to have the filename attached, like this:

```
/mybucketname/myfile
```

So the complete command could look like:

```
./s3-put -T ./test2 -k <mykey> -s ./<mysecretkeyfile> /mybucketname/myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with extension of file, my file was extension-less. 
Once i given the extension (in my case it was .zip), file uploaded successfully.