# Unable to upload image to Amazon s3 from Windows Phone using .NET SDK for Amazon

Tags: c#, file-upload, windows-phone-8, amazon-s3

I am using .NET SDK for Amazon S3 in my Windows Phone 8 project. I am using the following code,

```
public  async void UploadFile(string bucketName, string filepath)
    {
        string awsID = "myID";
        string secretKey = "mysecretkey";

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsID, secretKey);
        var request = new PutObjectRequest()
        {
            BucketName = "bucketname",
             InputStream = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("projectname;component/Assets/call.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream
        };

        await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine("File Uploaded");

    }
```

I have set the content type of image as "Resource"
 I am getting this error

XML is malformed from amazon s3.

On googling i found a link[s3-put fails to send file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244146/s3-put-fails-to-send-file)  asking me to append filename with name of the bucket.On doing so,I know get a folder created inside my bucket int he name of file and my contents are not uploaded.

Comment: Setting   ContentType="image/png", solved the issue!!

Answer (score 1):

For WinRT and Windows Phone FilePath property must be in the form of "ms-appdata:///local/file.txt" as mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html).

To upload from isolated storage you can use InputStream property.

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = "bucketname",
        InputStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile("YOUR_FILE_PATH", FileMode.Open);
    };
```

Comment: I have replaced file path with "ms-appdata:///local/myimage.png" still I get the same exception

Comment: Try, InputStream = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("../Assets/call.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream; instead of FilePath. Also did you try uploading a file from isolated storage?

Comment: Try to catch the exception and get the inner exception.

Comment: when i use filepath as ms-appdata, I get an exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)} .When I use InputStream, I get exception before executing putObjectAsync as {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @ Ritesh no for now I dnt try it from isolated storage,I m referencing local file